# How to LAN Minecraft when both computers are tethering using mobiles connected to a WiFi Hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, tethering

We had a problem when we tried using the LAN feature of Minecraft. We believe it was because tethering using our mobile phones to connect to the home wifi changes our default gateway. Any ideas?

We couldn't ping each other either...

Comment: Just connect to the same access point

Comment: We are connected to the same access point but by using tethering on our phones. So we can use the WiFi.

Comment: If your getting different gateways that doesn't make sense

Comment: are you using one phone or two?

Comment: We are using one phone each per our computers. We are connecting to the same access point.

Comment: do your computers have wifi or wired only?

Comment: They only have wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot work. When tethering, the phone creates its own subnet, where it places the tethered client. In other words, it NATs its client. So neither computer, in your case, belongs to your home WLAN. They belong to two separate, distinct, and incommunicado subnets. Your home WLAN acts, to them,  just as a network to cross, just like your ISP's.

If your two pcs had a wireless connection, the way to make it work would be to use **one** phone as a hotspot, because then both pcs would be placed inside the same LAN. This might stress the phone a bit, perhaps, since I am not sure it can handle that much traffic.

But, since your pcs do not have a wifi card, the above is impossible. I suggest you buy two cheap wifi USB dongles, you can have pretty decent ones for $20 or so.

Answer (score 1):

doesn't seems to be possible, as far as I know phone tethering is more like a hotspot than like a router, so there is no "physical" connection between the devices using the tethering.

If I haven't misunderstood, you should be able to create a network with one of the computers and connect the other to it.

Comment: We are basically using our phones as wireless cards to connect to my in home WiFi.